# When can I trust my translated content in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I'd like to verify my understanding of `v-html` and XSS concerns when using Vue I18n.

We have a few classes of content:

1. User supplied - user adds text to an input and the data will be display as-is on a page
2. Translator supplied - a translator using a CMS is adding content to translation files and we then show those values
3. Engineer supplied - an engineer is adding html to a translation file

#1 is outright untrustworthy

#2 could be trustworthy, but would require review (we will have generated translation files that will get added to a PR for the normal code review & QA process)

#3 is just trustworthy?  Is there a difference between an engineer adding html in a template vs a translation file.  Or is the mere fact that html could be in a translation file open us up to some sort of exploit?

There is a section on the [Vue I18n documentation](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html#basic-usage) that says,

> ...if you configure the  tag in a locale message, there is a
> possibility of XSS vulnerabilities due to localizing with
> v-html="$t('term')".

Is there an inherent XSS risk when using "Trusted Content" in a client side translation file?

Edit: After thinking about this it becomes dicey real quick.  If we allow `v-html` on a section of translation because we know the say a hyperlink is ok, but we also display something else like `company_name` there could be bad content in there.

I did a little checking and it looks like Rails handles this differently.  Even if a translation is marked as `_html`, the *values* supplied are still escaped, just the content itself is allowed to have html.

Example:
with `name = "<b>Name</b>"`

Rails -> `foo_html: "hi {name} <u>underlined text</u>"`
results in underlined text, but the name is not bold and the displayed content still has `<b>` around it (it ignores the html inside a supplied argument)

Vue I18n -> with v-html -> `foo: "hi {name} <u>underlined text</u>"`
the text is underlined, and the name is bolded, which is not safe

Answer (score 0):

You are asking several questions

> As long as content from #2 is audited for nefarious content, is it safe to use as raw html?

Yes and no. In theory, if you check every single message, and know the context of every single message, and never have time constraints so people check every single message before each release, you are fine. In practice, people cut corners, or do not know that a particular message will be inserted as html, or do not understand how some string might be malformed html, but get converted by the browser to valid html that is actually nefarious. Someone might get access to your CMS and change a translation string that you didn't expect to be changed. Someone might forge a form submission in your cms if it is not configured right by tricking an employee to visit an url.

> Or is the mere fact that html could be in a translation file open us up to some sort of exploit?

`v-html` is just that. It places html unfiltered in your document.

> What is that possibility, how does it work?

`v-html` with translated strings creates unnecessary risks and extra overhead by requiring a copywriter with extensive technical knowledge to check every single translation message, where instead you could have a copywriter without any technical knowledge do that. The only thing you need to do is use the pattern as outlined in the documentation, which allows anyone to change the translatable bits (which will be escaped), while keeping the html in your source control.

Comment: I am finding the pattern falls apart quickly when someone wants to add say a link to a block of copy.  Adding in a {0} or {link} and then the link parts is going to require more "extensive technical knowledge" than just pasting an anchor into a section.

Comment: If the CMS took in say markdown and that is translated into sanitized html does that remove any of the concerns?

Comment: I clarified the initial question based on your answer, thanks!